# PostgreSQL Case insensitive database/schema

Tags: database, postgresql

Is it possible to create a database or schema in PostgreSQL which is case insensitive?

Meaning below queries give me the same result.

`Select * from "emp" where "name" = 'DEEpak'`
or 
`Select * from "emp" where "name" = 'deepak'`

I know I can achieve this by using query

`Select * from "emp" where lower("name") = lower('deepak')`

Answer (score 1):

As superuser

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
```

Now define all text columns of your tables as type `citext`.

This type does case insensitive string comparison.